# Output of sum coming incorrect in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, sum

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 
   int sum[10]; char sex[10];
   int i,j,ans;

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {

    ans=0;
    printf("Enter your gender (m/f) : ");

    scanf("%c",&sex[i]);
    
    printf("\nEnter your total score for 8-Question by giving score (1-5) : \n");
    
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    {

        printf("Score : ");
        scanf("%d", &ans );
        sum[i]+=ans;       
    }

 //let say if input is 1 for 8 times sum should be 8 !

    printf("\n sum of score is %d.\n ",sum[i]);
    } 
    return 0;
    }
```

My output after giving input is not coming as addition of 8 inputs . I want to give 8 inputs and store it in array of sum. I want to add user 8 inputs and store in sum array.

Comment: You have an array of `sum`, where each iteration of the loop increments the next element, are you sure you don't want a single value instead?  `int sum=0` instead of `int sum[10]`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the input and the corresponding output. Maybe the newline from the first input doesn't get consumed. Try `scanf(" %d", &ans );` (note the space before `%d`). You should also check the return code of `scanf`. It will tell you the number of items that were successfully converted which should be 1 in your case.

Comment: You haven't initialize/zeroed `sum[10]`, thus you have an _'undefined behavior'_ regarding the result. `sum[i]+=ans;`=> `sum[i]=sum[i]+ans;`, if `sum[i]` is not 0 at start, then...

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The whole of stdio.h is unsafe. It's an very dangerous and harmful library overall. The sole purpose of it is to print stuff during beginner classes, it shouldn't be used for anything else.

Comment: Nite that you declare `i` and `j` twice in different scopes.  The outer declaration is unused.  Since `and` is only used in the `j` loop, it can be localised to that loop.  Essentially the `int i,j,ans;` is redundant

Comment: @Lundin  Another very strident opinion!  As a systems level language C is intrinsically "unsafe" in that it does not protect you from the consequences of writing bad code.  Certainly `scanf()` should be treated with extreme caution.  I would not express it quite as emphatically you have though.

Comment: @Clifford We have some 40 years of experience from using stdio.h in C programs by now. Measuring the damage done to mankind, I dare say that it ought to be the most harmful library ever developed by mankind, all categories. No other library for any programming language comes remotely close in terms of damage caused. Almost 100% of the functions in the library come with huge design flaws and well-documented vulnerabilities. It ain't going to be fixed, it took some 30 years just to get `gets` banned and that one is really just the top of the iceberg.

Comment: @Lundin  Yes, but your one-man campaign won't fix it (or scaring/confusing beginners with the rhetoric).  C++ already fixed it ;-)

Comment: @Clifford It's hardly a one man campaign, the entire library has been banned from production code by MISRA-C since the 1990s. And other coding standards like CERT C hand out lots of restrictions in use. And yeah C++ kind of fixed it, the way as it's always done in C++, by creating a tonne of other problems instead. But I won't disagree that iostream is a much better designed lib. I already realized as much back in the days when I was a confused beginner myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233659/discussion-between-clifford-and-lundin).

Answer (score 3):

The initial value of `sum[i]` is unknown if you don't initialise it.

```
int sum[10] = {0} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, by default `int sum[10]` garbage value and you are storing only 8 elements in array. So remaining to have garbage value.

Use `memset` before storing array.

```
memset(sum, '\0', 10);
memset(sex, '\0', 10);
```

Comment: You have initialised only 10 bytes of  `sum` -  2.5 elements on a 32 bit system.  You need `memset( sum, 0, sizeof(sum) )`.  Safer to do it at initialisation if setting to zero.  For `sex`  you get away with it because it happens to be `char` array, but you should use the same pattern in any case.